# Spring Batch - How to dynamically invoke a Step Configuration to reinitialise partitioner instance

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-batch, spring-bean, spring-batch-admin

I have a spring batch job consisting of ItemReader, ItemProcessor and NoOpItemWriter.
I have a rest controller that starts the job using some job parameters.

- The item reader reads from a list ( that is present in the servlet context)
- Item processor  takes the item and makes a DB call
- Item Writer does nothing
- The partitioner logic is an implementation of List Partitioner that partitions a list based on index ranges

Initially the servlet context is empty ( has one dummy item). So on bean initialization the list partitioner receives one dummy item.
Depending on what gets passed in the post request , the list is populated

The problem is, when the spring boot application starts, the **partitioner is already initialized with the dummy list contents**. I would like the partitioner to work on what gets passed as part of my rest controller.

Below is my Step , Job and Servlet bean configuration

```
@Bean(name = ["controllerStep"])
  protected fun controllerStep(
    jobRepository: JobRepository,
    transactionManager: PlatformTransactionManager
  ): Step {

    servletConfiguration.setServletContext()
    return StepBuilder("controllerStep", jobRepository)
      .partitioner(
        "workerStep",
        ListPartitioner(servletConfiguration.getItemProcessingList()!!.size)
      )
      .step(workerStep(jobRepository, transactionManager))
      .gridSize(6)
      .build()
  }


  @Bean
  fun job(jobRepository: JobRepository?, transactionManager: PlatformTransactionManager?): Job? {
    return JobBuilder("job", jobRepository!!)
      .start(controllerStep)
      .build()
  }
```

Below is the Servlet Configuration Class

```
@Configuration
class ServletConfiguration(private var servletContext: ServletContext) {

  fun setServletContext() {
    servletContext.setAttribute("DatatoBeProcessed", listOf(""))
  }
  @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
  fun getItemProcessingList(): List<String>? {
    val contextList = servletContext.getAttribute(ATTRIBUTE_NAME_PROCESSING_INPUT_DATA)
    return if (contextList != null) contextList as? List<String> else listOf("")
  }
}
```

Below is my Rest Controller: I would like the partitioner to acknowledge the below list that is set to the servlet context when the job is launched

```
dataService.setListsIntoServletContext(jobRequestDto)
```

```
  @PostMapping("/trigger")
  fun startJob(@RequestBody jobDTO: JobDTO): ResponseEntity<String> {

    // fetch list of items and save in servlet context
    dataService.setListsIntoServletContext(jobRequestDto)

    // create job parameters
    val jobParameters =
      JobParametersBuilder()
        .addString("JobUniquekey", Random.nextInt().toString()) // to-be refactored
        .addString(
          "status",
          jobDTO.status.toString(),
        )
        .addString("jobType", jobDTO.jobType.toString())
        .toJobParameters()

    // trigger job
    jobLauncher.run(job, jobParameters)
    return ResponseEntity("JOB trigger:SUCCESS", HttpStatus.ACCEPTED)
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

> I have a spring batch job consisting of ItemReader, ItemProcessor and NoOpItemWriter.

> Item Writer does nothing

This is a sign that something is wrong with that design. If the job does not write anything, how to consume its result?

> The problem is, when the spring boot application starts, the partitioner is already initialized with the dummy list contents. I would like the partitioner to work on what gets passed as part of my rest controller.

You need to decalre the partitioner as a step-scoped bean and configure it with the parameters coming from the request. You can find an example here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/reference/html/step.html#step-scope

Comment: This is a sign that something is wrong with that design. If the job does not write anything, how to consume its result? - The job would just read a list of items and pass on the list of items to an asyncprocessor to pass the info to some other api. My requirement did not have anything to write.

Comment: `to pass the info to some other api` is the write operation. Getting data from an API is a read operation. Posting data to an API is a write operation, which should be done in an item writer, not in an item processor.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Bean(name = ["controllerStep"])
@JobScope
protected fun controllerStep(
  jobRepository: JobRepository,
  transactionManager: PlatformTransactionManager,
  @Value("#{jobParameters['itemListSize']}") listSize: Long
): Step {
  return StepBuilder("controllerStep", jobRepository)
    .partitioner("workerStep", ListPartitioner(listSize.toInt()))
    .step(workerStep(jobRepository, transactionManager))
    .gridSize(6)
    .build()
}
```

The above helped with partition reinitializing.